# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 15, Size: 19

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

So I was combing through some logs from our web server the other day (looking for something else), when something peculiar caught my eye.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 15, Size: 19
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
```

This seemed impossible to me.

I looked up the source code for [ArrayList#rangeCheck](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.rangeCheck%28int%29) and it blew my mind

```
private void rangeCheck(int index) {
    if (index >= size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
}
```

Based on the the message that I received should never have happened.

Unfortunately I don't know what the contents were exactly at this time (this is called from code that's used for a lot of things). And I have been unable to reproduce it. I don't even know where I'd start.

The question: Should this be able to happen? Is this a glitch in Java? Or just a freak accident.

I recognize that this may be off topic. I wish I had more information about what happened, but I don't.

Comment: Is it possible you have a multi-threading problem?

Comment: are multiple threads operating on the array?

Comment: I never thought about multithreads. But it definitely makes sense. I'll investigate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ArrayList is not multithread safe. If it were being modified by one thread at about the time of an access by another thread, `index >= size` could have been true when the test was run, but false by the time the message was built.

Comment: Although I've read the code over for 30 minutes, and I know it's multithreaded, to me it looks like there's no way 2 different threads can both edit the **same** object. But I'm sure I'm making a mistake somewhere. I'll accept this.

Comment: You don't need them both to edit the same object. You just need one to modify it and, at a time after it starts modifying, another thread to do any form of access.

Answer (score 3):

> Should this be able to happen? Is this a glitch in Java? Or just a freak accident.

All the above.

Let us image you are adding to the ArrayList in one thread and accessing it in another.

Lets say you have a size of 14, but you access index 15

```
T1: if (index >= size) // is true
T2: for(int i=0;i<5;i++) list.add(N); // so now we have 19.
T1: outOfBoundsMsg(index); // Index: 15, Size: 19
```