# JTable RowSorter throws IndexOutOfBoundException even if index < size

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When I try to sort one column immediately after the Jtable is loaded, I get IndexOutOfBoundException even if index is lesser than the size. I feel that even if the table has finished loading, there  are some updates happening on the table model. Is there any way to detect if all the updates on the table model are finished?
I am using Jtable's AutoCreateRowSorter.
Thank you in advance. Below is the stacktrace.

```
`ERROR: 11:15:37,789  - 
Logger$IC_UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException:?

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 530, Size: 1637
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.rac.cif.common.CIFTableModel.getRowLine(Unknown Source)
    at com.my.dff.center.unified.table.MyCIFTableModelDFF.getValueAt(MyCIFTableModelDFF.java:51)
    at com.rac.cif.common.CIFTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter$TableRowSorterModelWrapper.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter$TableRowSorterModelWrapper.getStringValueAt(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.compare(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter$Row.compareTo(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.sort(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.setSortKeys(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultRowSorter.toggleSortOrder(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI$MouseInputHandler.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.rac.cif.common.CIFTable$1.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

Comment: Please add stack trace to your question. Stack trace is best indication what went wrong and where. Also it would be good to add source code related to place where exception is thrown

Comment: "even if index is lesser than the size". If the size is 5, in your case the index could be -4. Can you please show the actual code (or a short example in which the problem can be reproduced with exact information) ?

Comment: maybe this can provide an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24943122/indexoutofboundsexception-index-15-size-19

Comment: @Stultuske Thanks for the link. I know that concurrency is the problem. I think when I try to sort, RowSorter is trying to update the table and at the same time some background updates are also going on the table model. That is why I want to know the way by which I can check if the model updates are finished.

Comment: Swing components are inherently thread-unsafe. The only access to swing components, should be done from the UI thread. Schedule updates to the JTable using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, don't do them from a separate Thread.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).